# creating a new blank .txt file using matlab

Tags: matlab, createfile

How can I create a blank .txt file? I use Matlab R2014a.
I want to check whether file of specified name exists and if it does not, I want to create one.

Comment: This is easily google-able.. why not use that tool (google) in a first place?

Comment: Ok, but can you show what you have already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not like answering questions that just "ask" and provide no "I tried this...".

Nevertheless, there are many ways to accomplish what you are asking. This is one of them:

```
if exist('text.txt', 'file') == 0
 disp('File does not exist, creating file.')
 f = fopen( 'text.txt', 'w' );  
 fclose(f);
else
    disp('File exists.');
end
```

Answer (score 1):

to check if file exists, simply use the [`exist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html) command:

```
exist( filename, 'file' )
```

To create an empty file, you can simply use [`fopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) and [`fclose`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fclose.html):

```
if ~exist(filename, 'file' )
    fid = fopen(filename,'w');
    fclose(fid);
end
```

Comment: How can you overwrite an existing file?

Comment: probably too late, but to overwrite you use fprintf(fid,'your text'). You must open with 'w' to overwrite. If you want to append open with 'a'.